What happens if the first tournament round does not conclude before the second is scheduled to begin in a double-round day?
Some classical chess tournament schedule two rounds in the same day.  Rounds can go on for many hours, so I was wondering what happens if some players are still playing the first round when the second round is scheduled to begin in such a situation.
The only thing I could find in the FIDE Laws of Chess were guidelines for adjourning a round to be continued later, but that wouldn't really help when the next round needed to be paired.  How would this be handled?

According to the FIDE handbook C.04.2 General handling rules for Swiss Tournaments:

Adjourned games are considered draws for pairing purposes only.

So the second round can still be paired if the first is adjourned. The players are simply paired as if they had drawn.
If a tournament instead uses USCF rules, there are several methods that could be used to resolve the pairings during an adjournment. In one method, the tournament director asks the players if they want to offer a draw. Players who do not do so are paired as if they had won, and players who do are paired as if they had drawn. (And, of course, if both players offer a draw, the game is drawn instead of adjourned.)

In the case of a double-round day, if the first round goes longer than the expected time and clashes with the start of the second round, the later round is postponed by a couple of minutes/hours.

but that wouldn't really help when the next round needed to be paired

The pairings for the next round are only released after completing the previous round.
